# Promise en typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo el sgte metodo

```
loadScenarios() {
  this.aggregationService.loadScenarios().subscribe(
  response => {
     this.scenarios = response.scenarios
     //CODE
  },
  error => {
  }
  );
}
```

Del cual lo llamo de otro método

```
loadSimulation(id: number) {
  this.aggregationService.loadSimulation().subscribe(
  response => {
     this.loadScenarios();
     console.log("3")
     for (var sce in this.scenarios) {
           //CODE
     }
  },
  error => {
  }
}
```

Pero el console.log("3") lo muestra en consola y quiero que espere a que loadscenarios termine antes de que lo pinte

Comment: actualizado la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Estás usando Observables (supongo que estás con Angular) y promesas a la vez, eso no suele ser recomendable a menos que conozcas bien ambas.

No tiene sentido que esta función `loadScenarios` sea async porque estás devolviendo nada (obtienes un undefined).

Podrías hacer algo como:

```
loadSimulation(id: number) {
   this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res: any) => {
     const res1 = this.aggregationServiceloadScenarios().subscribe(response => {
     this.scenarios = response;
     console.log("3")
     for (var sce in this.scenarios) {
           //CODE
     }
   });
}
```

Aunque aún no entiendo por qué anidas dos llamadas si con la respuesta de la primera no estás haciendo nada...

Comment: realmente el metodo loadScenarios hace mas cosas a parte de this.scenarios = response;, por eso me interesa mas llamar al metodo en vez de solo al servicio,, lo puedo hacer como tu dices pero replicaria todo lo que tengo en loadsceanrios y es lo que queiro evitar. He modificado mi post original

Comment: Podrías usar entonces .pipe(tap(...)) para añadir cierta lógica dentro de loadScenarios, pudiendo dejar el resto del código como he puesto

Answer (score 0):

Si te es comodo trabajar con `await/async`, dentro del método `loadScenearios` tendrías que crear una `promise` y utilizar esta para manejar su resolución o rechazo.

**Ejemplo:**

```
async loadScenarios() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    this.aggregationService.loadScenarios().subscribe(
      response => {
        resolve(response.scenarios)
      },
      error => {
        reject(error)
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Así en el método `loadSimulation` podes usar `await`

**Ejemplo:**

```
loadSimulation(id: number) {
    this.http.get(this.url).subscribe((res: any) =>
      (async() => {
        this.scenarios = await this.loadScenarios();
        console.log("3")
        for (var sce in this.scenarios) {
          //CODE
        }
      })();
    }
```